# How to structure a service that has many variation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got my app ready, which rely on Ruby on Rails as backend.

Now I am going to publish another app, which has similar functionality, but different topic. like StackExchange, it has multiple sites under this big umbrella, like Stackoverflow, Superuser, Game Development etc.

I have these few approaches in mind:

1. Same code base, deploy to multiple Rails apps.
2. Same code base, handle by same Rails app, but with flagging. to identify.

How do Stackoverflow handle this kind of variation?

Comment: This may be a question for meta.stackexchange.com, and is similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: When you say "Similar functionality" - what's the difference?  If there's no difference in functionality you should say "the same functionality"

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier for you, initially, to have a single app handling the different sites, and to use the url to set some settings for each site, such as which data to load up, which stylesheets etc.  In this way you're designing a single rails app, and can test it easily with various localhost urls which trigger the different variants etc.

If your site becomes very successful you will want to split it across multiple servers anyway.  At that point, you will need to consider a strategy for doing so:  you may decide that you will have one server per site, or it might be the case that one of the sites is so massively successful that you need multiple servers for that and one to handle the others, or something else.  That's a nice problem to have, and you might not have it, so keep it simple for now is my advice.

EDIT - for info on how stackexchange works, go to http://blog.serverfault.com/ .  Searching for "architecture" could be a good start for you.